# How to pass parameters in jquerymobile on pagechange

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery-mobile

I am working with jquerymobile on a mobile app.
This mobile apps works together with a web service.
I call the web-service with user data to authenticate myself and then I want to display the returned data on the next page.

At the moment I have a button on the page with calls a javascript method that sends a post request to my web-service and then directs me to the next page depending on the result of the web-service call.
All that works fine but I have no idea how to display data from my webservice on page2.

All I could find are some ways to pass some static parameters via $.mobile.changepage($("#page2"))

Comment: I think you can only send data when using an AJAX page change. This can be done by the `data` option.

Comment: My understanding was, that that is only possible when refering to an external url. My page consists of a few divs so there are no external urls.

Comment: You can also do it without ajax page DOM loading, you will need to use localstorage. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**, there you will find 4 method of passing data during page transitions. Search for chapter: **Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions**, you will also find a few examples.